# WP 8.1 text scaling

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

So say I have a textblock with a fontsize 32. The value of the text property is a variable amount of characters. If the text at a fontsize of 32 is cut off, how could i down scale the fontsize until the total width of the textblock is equal to the page width?

-I'd post a screenshot but not enough rep :/

Comment: You might have to come up with a logic of your own. The Textbox's width to readable fontsize ratio could be a metric to start with.. The you could update the Fontsize on the TextChanged event. But changing FontSizes sounds to me a bad UX..

Comment: what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is insert the TextBlock inside a fix width ViewBox:

```
 <Viewbox Width="300" StretchDirection="Both" >
    <TextBlock x:Name="testblock" Foreground="Magenta" FontSize="24" Text="This is a test"/>
    </Viewbox>
```

And that will make the job without any effort. Change the parameters depending you need, and you can insert the textblock inside a border,etc.